Adding values to YAML file
`
I want to append an entry in namespaceAdmin,namespaceDebugger in the below yaml file using yq. Basically it has got multiple patches and I want to make changes in some of the helmrelease patches. Is that possible?
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1

kind: Kustomization

metadata:

  name: test

  namespace: flux-system

spec:

  interval: 10m0s

  sourceRef:

    kind: GitRepository

    name: applications

  patches:

      - patch: |-

          apiVersion: v1

          kind: Namespace

          metadata:

            name: test

            labels:

              app-name: test

      - patch: |-

          apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta2

          kind: HelmRelease

          metadata:

            name: test

          spec:

            values:

              roleBinding:

                namespaceAdmin:

                  - kk3@test.com

                  - kk2@test1.com

                  - kk1@test2.com

                namespaceDebugger:

                   - kk@test3.com

      - patch: |-

          apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta2

          kind: HelmRelease

          metadata




I tried yq select which fetches the entire helmrelease. But I can't add an entry
yq eval '.spec.patches[] | select(.patch | contains("HelmRelease") and .patch | contains("name: istio-rules") and .patch | contains("namespace: istio-system")) | .patch |= sub("(keyVault:\s- [^\n])"; "\1\n    - newKeyVaultEntry")' istio-rules.yaml

Looks like you want to YAML-decode the literal-style patches with @yamld, make some changes, and then re-encode them again with @yaml. Maybe something along the lines of
.spec.patches[].patch |= (
  @yamld
  | select(
      .kind == "HelmRelease" and
      .metadata.name == "istio-rules" and
      .metadata.namespace == "istio-system"
    ).keyVault += ["newKeyVaultEntry"]
  | @yaml
)

Use the --inplace (or -i) flag to update the file (without it, the result is just written to the terminal).

Thanks much for the solution. I managed to append the entries to the corresponding section by decoding and re-encoding the yaml
